# How do I get an Overlay image to follow elements that move in a video?

Tags: image, video

My video pans to the right. How do I get the overlaid elements to move *with* the video so that it seem integrated?

- image1: This is where I would like the overlay to stay (beside the 2nd from last tree on the right)
  [image]
- image2: The overlay element doesn't move when the camera pans to the right, it remains static.

[image]

Comment: You need to learn to use motion tracking, and use the position of the tracker to move other elements in the compositor or the 3D envirionment. Watch the series of videos on tracking called **"track, match, blend"** by Sebastian Koenig

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

The Transformation Tools add-on will simplify the process;:
https://github.com/tin2tin/VSE_Transform_Tools
As described in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/SWLRmTEX2tc